# Android - How can I change the default message "Complete action using"

Tags: android

I would like to know how can I change the default message "Complete action using" in my Intent.

Comment: You are talking about that message ? [linkishere](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-4/303663-complete-action-using-option.html)

Comment: Please supply the code that you are using to create the `Intent` and call `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
...

String title = "My default launcher title";
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);

// Verify the intent will resolve to at least one activity
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are referencing a choice that the system provides for you when you use a built-in system Intent.  In these particular circumstances, the intent is not in your control at that point.  Other than receiving a result back from it and using it for your own purposes.

However, if you want to change the dialog, then you will have to implement your own chooser dialog.  Which would entail asking the system for what services are available for the task you are doing (picture viewer for example) and then load the information returned into your own layout.  I do believe that this approach is possible, but it's a lot of work to go about replacing a dialog screen.  You are probably better off just using the defaults.  After-all, that is the experience that we expect from the user end.